# Keyboard shortcut to sort by column

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, windows-explorer

I've been looking for a keyboard shortcut to sort a folder by name. Can anybody enlighten me on to one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shortcut for this purpose is **not listed** in [Microsoft website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583)

---

You could Do this

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> - to perform Right Click
- <kbd>I</kbd> - to Select Arrange Icons by..
- <kbd>N</kbd> - To Arrange by Name
- <kbd>S</kbd> - To Arrange by Size
- <kbd>T</kbd> - To Arrange by Type
- <kbd>M</kbd> - to Arrange by Modified

  ---

You could use install **[Altap Salamandar](http://www.altap.cz/salam_en/help/salamand/shortcuts_keyboard.htm)**.

> After which these settings would
>   become effective
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> Display the Drive Information dialog
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> Change attributes of the selected files and directories
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> Sort files and directories in the active panel by name. Press the
>   key again to reverse sort order.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> Sort files and directories in the active panel by extension.
>   Press the key again to reverse sort
>   order.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> Sort files and directories in the active panel by time. Press the
>   key again to reverse sort order.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> Sort files and directories in the active panel by size. Press the
>   key again to reverse sort order.

Comment: +1 for referring to the reference list from Microsoft.

Comment: +1 for "Shift+F10". Been wondering about it as my work laptop didn't have the "Right Click" button, but didn't search for it as finding it unbearably non-ergonomic, I plugged in an external keyboard very soon.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>

This will zip you through the menu to sort by name.

You can change the last letter to:

- <kbd>S</kbd> for **SIZE**
- <kbd>T</kbd> for **TYPE**
- <kbd>M</kbd> for **DATE MODIFIED**

**EDIT:**

I continued to search for you, and found multiple references to indicate this is not possible.

[Here](http://thedailyreviewer.com/xphelp/view/keyboard-shortcut-to-change-explorer-view---toggle-views-1011246204), [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-490668.php), [reference to other methods mentioned here](http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/windowsxp/articles/573/2/Windows-XP-FAQ-S), and a [comprehensive list of windows XP shortcuts from MS here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583).

Comment: This is helpfull, but there is a faster one without opening any menus, but I can't remember it :(

Comment: You can rightclick then do I->N, but I dont think there is a DIRECT kb shortcut in native windows xp for this function.

Comment: If you can't remember it, you can make a simple AutoHotKey script to map any key combination to "Alt-V, I, N"

Answer (score 1):

A faster shortcut.
Tab > Arrows > Enter

In detail:
Being in a folder through windows explorer, selecting one of her files.
Press TAB - Some header column of the folder will be selected
Use arrows - Until you choose the header you want to use as a classification parameter
Press Enter - To confirm the classification

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows10, the new combo is:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

They have done away with the last shortcut, so if you wish to sort by anything other than name, you must arrow <kbd>Down</kbd> to your choice and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>